# Editing _extend.less workflow extremely slow

Tags: magento2.3

I'm pretty new in Magento.

I'm a little confused about customizing theme CSS, by editing _extend.less file. Magento documentation says that this is the simplest way to edit theme CSS. 
But any time I change a line in the less file I need to completely clear the pub/static and preprocessed folder, then run static deploy: this is *extremely* slow.

By enabling developer mode, which should be changing things in realtime, the site/admin is super slow, not practicable.

Is there a way such as save and refresh?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way you can directly able to see your changes out **with run all Commands**:

Basically you need to Understand This logic behind the **CSS** and **JS**.

> Once you **Deploy** and **Compile** in Magento2 this creates new files of JS and CSS in **View Preprocessed Folder**

So You have to first Directly Edit your file in View Preprocessed folder then replicate it into your module.

For this Specified Path: `Magento_root/Var/view_processed/pub/static/frontend/Magento/ThemeName/Language/ModuleName/CSS/yourfileName.css`

**Hope you Understand !!**